# What is "Remote Target" in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I open ⋮ More tools ► Remote devices, I see the following:

[image: Image of the Remote devices tab]
CLT-L29 is a phone connected to the computer, and can be debugged fine. But what is the meaning of the "Remote Target" tab on the left?